# Multiselect Spinner CheckBox I want to Show Toast in dialog when I am click on 'OK'

Tags: android

I have Created Multiselect spinner with checkbox but if in case nothing selected from spinner I have click on 'Ok' then show toast please give solution

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
    if (mSelection != null && which < mSelection.length) {
        mSelection[which] = isChecked;

        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Argument 'which' is out of bounds.");
    }
}


@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(_items, mSelection, this);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {





        }
    });

    builder.show();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following line of code to show toast on dialog button click listener

```
       CharSequence[] items={"One","Two"};
       boolean isAnyCheckboxTick=false;
       AlertDialog.Builder builder =
               new AlertDialog.Builder(context);


       builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

              isAnyCheckboxTick=true;
           }
       });
       builder.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              if(!isAnyCheckboxTick)
              Toast.makeText(context,"Ok Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });

       builder.show();
```

Comment: I want Toast when user is not click single check-box and click on OK then display Toast

Comment: You can use a boolean flag to keep track of ticked checkbox items.